# Calculate the given integral neatly

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I study statistics related to kernel. While calculating the kernel, I stuck at the following integral problem. Here's the simplified version of the integral that I want to make it shorter as possible .Let's say I have $N \text{ continuous and nonnegative functions } f_1(x) \text{,} f_2(x) \text{,} \cdots 
\text{,}f_N(x) \text{.}$ Here, $x \text{ is the } n \text{ dimensional vector such that } x=(x_1, \cdots , x_n)^t \text{ . }$
Also, $\int_{[0,1[^n} f_1(x) dx = \int_{[0,1]^n} f_2(x) dx= \cdots \int_{[0,1]^n} f_N(x)dx=1 \text{.}$

For some fixed $N$ , $N > n \text{ , I want to calculate the following integral.} $
$$  \int_{[0,1]^n} f_1(x)\{\frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots f_N(x)}+\frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)+\cdots +f_N(x)}
+ \cdots + \frac{f_n(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots + f_N(x)} \}dx      
  +
\int_{[0,1]^n} f_2(x)\{\frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots f_N(x)}+\frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)+\cdots +f_N(x)}
+ \cdots + \frac{f_n(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots + f_N(x)} \}dx
+ \cdots + \int_{[0,1]^n} f_n(x)\{\frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots f_N(x)}+\frac{f_2(x)}{f_1(x)+\cdots +f_N(x)}
+ \cdots + \frac{f_n(x)}{f_1(x)+ \cdots + f_N(x)} \}dx$$

Is there any way to reduce this integral neatly?
If possible, I want to the eliminate the denomianator term and use the fact that $n$ continuous functions integrate to 1.

Comment: It seems to me that the integral is equal to $$\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Is there any reason you presented the integral in an expanded form?

Comment: There's no reason that I presented the integral in the expanded form. I was just trying to make the expanded form shorter as possible. I will check your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah. Your suggestion is right. But, I was wondering if I could use my original assumption that n continous functions integrate to 1

Comment: $N$ is larger than $n$.

Comment: My bad, sorry for bothering you, I deleted the comment

Comment: If $N>n$, then what does $f_{n+1}$ mean? That function was not defined according the conditions you have set up. Is it nonnegative? Does it sum to $1$ like the others? Where is the proper context for this calculation and why did it come up?

Comment: Oh! For $f_(n+1)$ it also integrates to 1.  I will edit my question. And actually there's no proper context for this calculation. I just want to know whetehr I can reduce this integral. Because for my statistics research, it seems like I have to deal with this kind of integral.